# How to add value into textbox of a frame

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to add value into a textbox of a frame. I tried this :

```html
ActiveSheet.Frame1.TextBox1.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value + ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value
```

But that way isn't working at all. How the right way to pull a value from sheet into the textbox of a frame. For your information, the textbox is created by right-clicking the frame and select 'Edit' to insert a new frame object control object. By right, it should appear 90 as the answer in the textbox. Please assist, thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, let's consider a case when TextBox1 is placed directly on the sheet. Following piece of code would change TextBox1 value:

```
ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Value = 5
```

As your TextBox1 control is placed within Frame1 you may try to refer to it in the following way:

```
ActiveSheet.Frame1.Controls("TextBox1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value + ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: It worked eventually, very much appreciate for your help :)